# File Dependency Caching in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement file dependency caching in mvc3. As I am new to MVC, I browsed searched google but I didn't get any help.

Can any of our guys help me out? or what is the work around for this?

I tried same as what we do in asp.net but I get error.

Code I tried:

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        Cache.Insert("DropDownData", "", new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("~/testxml.xml")));

        return View();
    }
```

Error That i got:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(string, object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert
```

`System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache` is the cache instance of your current application.

Comment: thanks it works as i expected. then using this type of caching is recommended in mvc3 or not?

Comment: you might be interested in this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx Hanselman even talks about using this technique outside of web applications as it is suitable for many situations. To say it short, you are doing it the right way in MVC using the `HttpRuntime.Cache`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling the instance method  `Cache.Insert` without a reference to an instance of the cache.  ASP.NET MVC does not expose the default Cache in the Controller by Default.

### In order to access it from the controller, you need to use `HttpContext.Cache.Insert`

That being said, this kind of behavior is more appropriately localized in an ActionFilter.  Check out the following for more on this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Answer (score 0):

Have you added reference correctly ?

Try to make an object likewise

```
CacheDependency CDep = new CacheDependency(fileName /*your file path*/, dt /*Set Start parameter to current date */);
```

and then use `insert` as

```
cache.Insert("DropDownData", "", CDep);
```